# Using concatMap to create list of average

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a list of average spa rating by using concatMap. However, due to the initial function for creating average from selecting spa rating in list, it causes these errors. Is there a way to retain concatMap and get an average list? Or is there other efficient way to get average list? The input comes from the database.

```
Couldn't match type 'Float' with '[(String, Int)]' 

Expected Type: [Float] -> [String]
Actual Type: [[(String, Int)]] -> [String]

Couldn't match type 'Float' with '[String]' 

Expected Type: [(String, Int)] -> [String]
Actual Type: [[(String, Int)]] -> Float
```

Input from spa rating(The number value)

```
[("Bryan", 7), ("Petrina", 9), ("Justin", 4), ("Janice", 7), ("Jason", 4)]
```

Expected output

```
[5.63, 8.56, 5.55]
```

```
type SpaID = String
type Name = String
type Location = String
type Stars = Int
type Supervisor =  String 
type SpaRating = Int 

data Spa = Spa SpaID Name Location Stars [(Supervisor, SpaRating)]

testDatabase = [

                Spa  "01" "Alma by Juan Amador" "Orchard" 3 
                [("Bryan", 7), ("Petrina", 9), ("Justin", 4), ("Janice", 7), ("Jason", 4)],

                Spa  "02" "Basque Kitchen by Aitor" "Tanjong Pagar" 1 
                [("Colin", 9), ("Nixon", 5), ("Julien", 7), ("Cheryl", 8), ("Sam", 8)],
                
                Spa  "03" "Beni" "Orchard" 1 
                [("Julien", 9), ("Cheryl", 6), ("Justin", 4), ("Janice", 5), ("Jason", 8)]

]

--spa average rating
averagespaRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averagespaRating avgsparating = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd avgsparating)) / (fromIntegral(length avgsparating))

-- turn into a list of average spa rating
avgSpaRatingListStr :: [Float] -> [String]
avgSpaRatingListStr = concatMap averagespaRating

-- turn spa into String
spaStr :: Spa -> String
spaStr spa@(Spa sid na ar st xs)
    = "SpaID: " ++ sid ++ ", Name: " ++ na ++ ", Area: " ++
      ar ++ ", Stars: " ++ show st ++ ", ServiceLevelRating: " ++ show (averageSpasRating xs)  ++ "\n"
```

Comment: The error is saying that the type declared for `avgSpaRatingListStr` is wrong. How do you want to be able to use that function? Maybe some example input and output would help us understand your goal.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Yes, that's better. But it looks like your expected output isn't valid. The last value contained in a `Spa` value must be of type `[(Supervisor, SpaRating)]`. It can't be a `Float`, like `5.63`. Did you mean for your expected output to just be `5.63`?

Comment: yes, just a two decimal place output.

Comment: The average list should just purely be average of each different spa which will then added to the back of spa in replacement of supervisor and spa rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `concatMap` has type `Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`. So if `concatMap some_func` must have type `[Float] -> [String]` (this is type of your function `avgSpaRatingListStr`), function `some_func` must have type `Float -> [String]`. I don't know what this function can do useful:

```hs
concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a  ->  [b]
                               |          |        |
                           some_func   [Float]  [String]

some_func :: Float -> [String]
```

You can insert this code:

```hs
getSupervisors :: Spa -> [(Supervisor, SpaRating)]
getSupervisors (Spa _ _ _ _ supervisors) = supervisors

averageSpasRating :: [Spa] -> [Float]
averageSpasRating = (<$>) (averagespaRating . getSupervisors)
```

Instead function `getSupervisors` you can redefine type `Spa`:

```hs
data Spa =
     Spa {
        getId :: SpaID,
        getName :: Name,
        getLocation :: Location,
        getStars :: Stars,
        getSupervisors :: [(Supervisor, SpaRating)]
     }
```

and receive function `getSupervisors` and other automaticaly.

Comment: Sorry, I just need a list of average rating for spa because I have my own code for creating a spa to string. I have some code using that so I cannot use the code you provide. Sorry...

Comment: It's working but when I try to add to my spaStr. It says it couldn't match expected type '[Char]' with actual type 'IO()'.  This is how I replace it with print (averageSpasRating).

Comment: Replace `print (averageSpasRating)` to `show (averagespaRating xs)`

Comment: It say it couldn't match type `(Supervisor, SpaRating)' with 'Spa'
Expected type: [Spa]
Actual type: [(Supervisor, SpaRating)]

Comment: `averagespaRating`, not `averageSpasRating`

Comment: I type in terminal spaStr testDatabase. It says 
 * Couldn't match expected type `Spa' with actual type `[Spa]'
    * In the first argument of `spaStr', namely `testDatabase'
      In the expression: spaStr testDatabase
      In an equation for `it': it = spaStr testDatabase

Comment: try `spaStr <$> testDatabase`

Comment: it is because `spaStr :: Spa -> String`, but `testDatabase :: [Spa]`

Comment: It works! Thank you!!!  But what does <$> represent? () ? How did it change to 1 decimal place? Is it possible to modify to 2 decimal place?

Comment: `<$>` has type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and in your case `f = []`, so `<$>` is synonym of `map`

Comment: you can look for more information in Hoogle (not Google)

Comment: Sorry, may I ask if it is possible to use printf %.2f for the float? Because I try placing it and it gives me error.

Comment: @RickPo you can look at [Text-Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) in Hackage